# nicEdit -- background color option

Tags: nicedit

I am using `nicEdit` for my solution where I can edit my html pages. All options provided by nicEdit are working fine but the background color option throws error in nicEdit-latest.js file at the following line of code.

```
nicCommand: function (B, A) { document.execCommand(B, false, A); }
```

The error is thrown at document.execCommand(B, false, A); and the error is:

> "0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this issue. I believe that the issue is in the browser you are using. nicEdit is hard-coded to execute the browser command "hiliteColor", but I believe it was Internet Explorer that is not compatible with that command which instead needed "backcolor". I cannot confirm this right now as compatibility mode in IE11 has no problem with hiliteColor, but this may be worth trying if you are still kicking nicEdit around -- I'm a little late on the draw here.